# HBase error while creatng table

Tags: ubuntu, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am new to HBase and I am learning it on my own. I install HBase and tried to create a table using the following command

`hbase(main):008:0> create 'htest', 'cf'`

but I am thrown a ton of error. This is what comes up:

> 2016-05-27 02:51:12,835 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master. 2016-05-27
>   02:51:13,038 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master. 2016-05-27
>   02:51:13,339 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master. 2016-05-27
>   02:51:13,843 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master. 2016-05-27
>   02:51:14,848 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master. 2016-05-27
>   02:51:16,852 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master. 2016-05-27
>   02:51:20,873 ERROR [main]
>   client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is
>   not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the
>   value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a
>   mismatch with the one configured in the master.
>
> ERROR: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been
>   written by the master. Check the value configured in
>   'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one
>   configured in the master.
>
> Here is some help for this command: Creates a table. Pass a table
>   name, and a set of column family specifications (at least one), and,
>   optionally, table configuration. Column specification can be a simple
>   string (name), or a dictionary (dictionaries are described below in
>   main help output), necessarily including NAME attribute. Examples:
>
> Create a table with namespace=ns1 and table qualifier=t1 hbase> create
>   'ns1:t1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}
>
> Create a table with namespace=default and table qualifier=t1 hbase>
>   create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'} hbase> #
>   The above in shorthand would be the following: hbase> create 't1',
>   'f1', 'f2', 'f3' hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL
>   => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE => true} hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', CONFIGURATION => {'hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles' => '10'}}
>
> Table configuration options can be put at the end. Examples:
>
> hbase> create 'ns1:t1', 'f1', SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40']
>   hbase> create 't1', 'f1', SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40'] hbase>
>   create 't1', 'f1', SPLITS_FILE => 'splits.txt', OWNER => 'johndoe'
>   hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}, METADATA => {
>   'mykey' => 'myvalue' } hbase> # Optionally pre-split the table into
>   NUMREGIONS, using hbase> # SPLITALGO ("HexStringSplit", "UniformSplit"
>   or classname) hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO
>   => 'HexStringSplit'} hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit', REGION_REPLICATION => 2, CONFIGURATION
>   => {'hbase.hregion.scan.loadColumnFamiliesOnDemand' => 'true'}}
>
> You can also keep around a reference to the created table:
>
> hbase> t1 = create 't1', 'f1'
>
> Which gives you a reference to the table named 't1', on which you can
>   then call methods.

I have no idea what to do! Any help is appreciated!

Also, should I have had configured Zookeeper before I installed HBase? My tutorial didn't say so.

Comment: Also, when I `list`, another error throws up. Please help!

Comment: Any solution yet ?
Facing the same problem.

Comment: Lol, nope. No one seems to care. I've since removed Ubuntu and installed Mint and got the same bloody error.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson, I had a similar issue connecting to Hbase remotely from my java code. Below is what helped me fix the problem. First, on your cluster (or linux node) type command "zookeeper-client" and then "ls /". Check if "hbase" directory is created (Ctr + D to exit from zookeeper-client). If not set the property of "zookeeper.znode.parent" to "/hbase-unsecure". This worked for me. I can share my java test code if it helps

Comment: @Rag, Thanks for that. Let me give that a shot. Btw, I'm not doing it using Java. Its just the regular (hbase) shell.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Good luck. I guess you can embed this in a property.xml file and use it.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson By the way, i read your comment about zookeeper in the problem statement. Your hbase configuration property "hbase.zookeeper.quorum" should point to the zookeeper. Else my recommended commands wont work. I was able to run table creation command in my machine and it works fine (hbase shell).

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the HBase log for the errors, most commonly the solution is setting correct parameters in the HBase-env.sh file.

Please refer to the link below. Its working for me perfectly.

https://sarangmanjrekar.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/node-hbase-is-not-in-zookeeper/